# Is it possible to use nokia's QTimer on a MFC app?

Tags: qt

i have qt installed on my com with the QT directories set in the mfc project properties. then I tired #include  but receive the follow errors.

```
1>c:\qt\4.6.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.h(47) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qbasictimer.h': No such file or directory
1>c:\qt\4.6.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.h(47) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qbasictimer.h': No such file or directory
```

i did a check under the QtCore folder and the qbasictimer.h file is there. so now im wondering if my app need to be a Qobject app inorder to use its Qtimer? is there any way i can use for my MFc program? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even if you solve the include path problem, I think that QTimer will depend on a running QMainloop.

Why would you want to do that anyway? Isn't there a timer class in MFC?(I absolutely have no idea about W32, just to add.)

Comment: i know there a timer class in mfc/c++ but i need to use qtimer and qsettings for my project but now im facing these errors, so im wondering is it impossible to do it.

Comment: why don't you write your app with qt entirely?